# Array/ArrayList to make order with scanner input

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

so my teacher ordered me to make a program that

1. ask the user for the size of the array with a scanner
2. the program is required to understand if there is a scanner with the word "add" it will add the word after it to the array
3. The commands that are required to exist are ADD, DELETE, VIEW for display index-n and DISPLAY for display all of them

this is an example I've made but it's still far from correct, please help me!!!

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    int a = input.nextInt();
    String arr[] = new String[a];
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        for (int j=0;j<arr.length;j++){
        arr[i] = input.nextLine();
        }
    }
    for( String b : arr ){
        System.out.println(b);
    }
enter code here
```

an example of the scanner input is

```
7
ADD this
ADD IS
ADD not
ADD real
VIEW 2
DELETE not
DISPLAY
```

and the output will be

```
not
this is real
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to ask how long the array should be because we are using ArrayList which is a dynamic array. You can make this code easier to read but here's just an example of what you are looking for:

```
public final static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        final Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true)
        {
            final String command = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase();

            if (command.contains("add "))
            {
                list.add(command.replace("add ", ""));
            } else if (command.contains("delete "))
            {

                final String toDelete = command.replace("delete ", "");
                if (!list.remove(toDelete))
                    System.out.format("\"%s\" didn't exist in the array!", toDelete);

            } else if (command.contains("view "))
            {
                System.out.println(list.get(Integer.parseInt(command.replace("view ", ""))));
            } else if (command.equals("display"))
            {
                for (final String str : list)
                {
                    System.out.println(str);
                }
                break;
            } else
            {
                System.out.println("Unknown command!");
            }
        }
        scan.close();
    }
```